# How can a submodule import a trait from the root in lib.rs?

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I have a `src/lib.rs` that contains:

```
pub trait Compile {
    fn from_source(src: &src) {
        parser::parse(src);
    }
}
```

And a `src/compiler/interpreter.rs`

```
use crate::Compile; // ERROR HERE - No Compile in the root

pub struct Interpreter;

impl Compile for Interpreter {}
```

I also have a `src/compiler.rs`

```
pub mod interpreter;
```

I want to be able to use the Compile trait within my interpreter impl however I cannot seem to figure out how import the trait. Any thoughts?

Its possible to do this in `src/main.rs` by doing:

```
mod lib;
use lib::Compile;
```

Comment: Is `Compile` vs `Compiler` just a typo?

Comment: @kmdreko yes you are correct that was a typo. I have updated my question!

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this issue was in `src/main.rs` I used:

```
use {ROOT CRATE PACKAGE NAME}::Compile;
```

This must bring `Compile` into the `crate` scope so now I can just do: `use crate::Compile` inside my `compiler` sub module.